# PHP Storm - espaços

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Alguém sabe por que o PHP Storm fica corrigindo automaticamente o excesso de espaços?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque ele deve estar configurado para isso. Se não deseja esse comportamento basta configurar para tal.

Comment: Sabe como tirar essa config, pois não lembro de ter mexido pra isso acontecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> ou menu Projeto. E desmarque as opções de auto formatação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Valeu @marcos-padilha . Não achei esta opção no windws, mas usando o mesmo raciocínio achei esta outa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]